# Make Reusable Component Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, code-reuse

i want to make a reusable livewire component from the code below

**searchfilm.blade.php**

```
             @foreach ($inputs as $key => $value)
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <select class="custom-select" wire:model="selectServer.{{ $value }}">
                            <option value="" selected>Server Name</option>
                            @foreach ($servers as $idData => $nameData)
                                <option value="{{ $idData }}">{{ $nameData }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    **<div class="input-group-append">
                        <select class="custom-select" wire:model="selectQuality.{{ $value }}">
                            <option value="" selected>Quality</option>
                            @foreach ($qualities as $idData => $nameData)
                                <option value="{{ $idData }}">{{ $nameData }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>**
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

I've tried to change it to

**searchfilm.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($inputs as $key => $value)
     @livewire('dropdown', ['title' => 'Server Name', 'data' => $servers, 'x' => $value])
     @livewire('dropdown', ['title' => 'Quality', 'data' => $qualities, 'x' => $value])
@endforeach
```

**dropdown.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <select class="custom-select" wire:model="selectData.{{ $x }}">
            <option value="" selected>{{ $title }}</option>
            @foreach ($data as $idData => $nameData)
                <option value="{{ $idData }}">{{ $nameData }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

but not work, any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Similar to VueJs, if you render a component inside a loop, Livewire has no way of keeping track of which one is which. To remedy this, livewire offers a special "key" syntax:

**searchfilm.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($inputs as $key => $value)
     @livewire('dropdown', ['title' => 'Server Name', 'data' => $servers, 'x' => $value], key($key))
     @livewire('dropdown', ['title' => 'Quality', 'data' => $qualities, 'x' => $value], key($key))
@endforeach
```

Please refer the following section **Keeping Track Of Components In A Loop** in https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components